# Get Contents Of Image Class From AutomationElement

Tags: automation, ui-automation, automationelement

I am walking controls in a third party app that contains images. The automation element returns the class name Image, Any ideas on how I can get the contents of that Image as a bitmap object, or even bytes?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old, I wanted to add an answer as I came across this problem as well.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace AutomationElementExtension
{
    public static class AutomationElementExtension
    {
        public static Bitmap ToBitmap(this AutomationElement automationElement)
        {
            var boundingRectangle = automationElement.Current.BoundingRectangle;
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(Convert.ToInt32(boundingRectangle.Width), Convert.ToInt32(boundingRectangle.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(Convert.ToInt32(boundingRectangle.X), Convert.ToInt32(boundingRectangle.Y), Point.Empty.X, Point.Empty.Y, bitmap.Size);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then get the image as a bitmap by calling it as

```
var bitmap = myAutomationElement.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

This discussion can be useful: [Capturing an image behind a rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397176/capturing-an-image-behind-a-rectangle) .

Just use BoundingRectangle property of the AutomationElement to make a snapshot.