# Sample Android Code for moving an image behind a selection box

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-image

I am looking for a sample code/app that can take a picture with the camera and then have the ability to crop it, specifically using the method of moving/zooming the image behind a selector box like the current google photos editor does.

bonus points if you can find something for xamarin :)

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9397176/411094), but i am looking for a more complete example.

Comment: Better to find and use any crop library. Because your question is much bigger.

Comment: One library is https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Comment: check one more... https://github.com/markuspalme/cropimage-xamarin